# How to merge two halfs of a sorted list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I have an integer linked list of which both first half and second half are sorted independently.Now i need to merge two parts to create one single sorted linked list.

Sample input:

Input List 1: `1->2->3->4->5->1->2` 

Output :  `1->1->2->2->3->4->5`

Input List 2: `1->5->7->9->11->2->4->6` 

Output 2: `1->2->4->5->6->7->9->11`

**Expected output:**

**1,2,3.....**

Comment: The expected final output is `1,2,3`? Why is that?

Comment: Naively this is the same as sorting an initially unsorted list, for which there are a number of [common solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: Does your linked-list implementation provide an iterator interface and `begin()` and `end()` style functions? In that case you can use the `std::merge` algorithm: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge

Comment: @billz The expected output is still not really clear. I assumed it's `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,9,11`. But perhaps it is `1,2,4,5`, in which case we need an intersection algorithm.

Comment: @jogojapan This is two separate test cases. Each one has two sorted groups in a single linked list. So the outputs are `1,1,2,2,3,4,5` for test case 1 and `1,2,4,5,6,7,9,11` for test case 2. So it's merge sort, not set intersection.

Comment: Mak, do you already have a pointer to the second half of the list? If so, you want to split the list at that point, and then merge the two separate lists. If not, you can just walk the list until you find a node that's less than the previous node, and then you have the pointer you need to split on.

Comment: @abarnert Great. If the OP agrees with this interpretation, it would be fantastic if the expected output in the question was corrected....

Comment: There is nothing specific to c++ here nor did the OP use any code. I removed the tag but it should be removed from question title too

Comment: @jogojapan: It's pretty clear that's what he wants. Each separate input is clearly "an integer linked list of which both first half and second half are sorted independently", and each corresponding output is clearly the result of merge-sorting the two halves. It is a bit confusing to then give the output format as "expected output", so I can see why you were thrown.

Comment: @jogojapan: PS, you should write your std::merge suggestion as an answer. The OP originally specifically asked about C++. So, even if he's not already using an STL-compatible type, learning how to write a standard iterator for his list is probably as useful a skill as learning how to write a merge sort from scratch…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merge sort.

I will maintain two pointers:

`ptr1` points to the first half's first element

and `ptr2` points to the second half's first element.

you will need an extra array to store the final list, of course you can choose not to use this extra array, but that discussion is far away from the topic.

**1,** Compare `*ptr1` and `*ptr2`, if `*ptr1`'s value is smaller than `*ptr2`, then copy that value(i.e. `*ptr1`) to the final array, and let `ptr1` move forward.

if `ptr2`'s value is the smaller one, just copy `*ptr2` and let `ptr2` move forward

**2,** Stop when the pointer points after the last element, say if you have 5 elements in the first half `a[0] a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4]`, then you should stop when the pointer points to
`a[5]`

**3,** If the first half is empty, then copy the rest of the second half, vice versa.

Comment: The particular step is called merge which joins two already sorted lists/arrays in O(n). He would probably not need a new list. Instead of copying elements you can always swap pointers

Comment: Oh yeap, he said he has one big list which first half and second half is sorted, I'm saying the steps for two separated lists.

Comment: That's the point. If both of them are actual link lists (and not arrays) it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Look [here](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2010/08/merge-sort-implementation-in-c.html) and [here](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/dsrkg/cs210/applets/sortingII/mergeSort/mergeSort.html) for implemetation details.

Answer (score 0):

Look for natural merge sort for optimal solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort

Answer (score 0):

I have done that countless time when using functional languages, so I guess I can give you a short explanation.

It's easier to grasp the idea if you think of it as a recursive process, but I'll give you the imperative one.
You start off with both your partial lists, and an empty sorted list.

Then you start your loop, your partial lists can be seen as:

- both empty, in which case your processing is done,
- one of them empty, you append the other to your sorted list,
- a couple of  head elements and the tails of the lists, where you will compare both heads, add the smallest to your sorted list, leave the other one in its original place, then loop with your remaining lists.

Once out of the loop you just return the sorted list.

There's one caveat though: if you are using simple linked lists, you'll get better running time by adding the elements in front of the sorted list, and reverse it at the end before returning it.

Comment: damn, typing that on a smartphone sucks. :)

Comment: That's because you can't just recursively type the first character and then the rest; you need an algorithm with explicit backtracking. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
        int[] ret = new int[left.length + right.length];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (; i < left.length & j < right.length;) {
            if (left[i] < right[j]) {
                ret[i + j] = left[i++];
            } else if (left[i] > right[j]) {
                ret[i + j] = right[j++];
            } else {
                ret[i + j] = left[i];
                ret[i + j + 1] = left[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }

        if (i < left.length) {

            copyIntArray(left, i, left.length, ret, ret.length - i);
        } else if (j < right.length) {

            copyIntArray(right, j, right.length, ret, ret.length - j);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    void copyIntArray(int[] src, int startIndex, int endIndex, int[] des, int desStartIndex) {
        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
            des[desStartIndex++] = src[i];
        }
    }
```